# Reading column index of selected table row in UI5 application

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I want to read column index of user selected row in a `sap.m.Table`. I tried few ways during debugging but not working. I am able to get the columns but not it's index.

Please find the table output screenshot attached below where I need to capture the table header(quarter name) when user selected any value.

[image]

**header.controller.js**

```js
sap.ui.define([
 "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
 "sap/ui/model/Filter",
 "NPAWRMA/model/formatter",
 "sap/ui/model/FilterOperator"
], function(Controller, Filter, formatter, FilterOperator) {
 "use strict";

 return Controller.extend("NPAWRMA.controller.header", {
  formatter: formatter,
  onInit: function(evt) {

  },
  onPress: function(oeve) {
  debugger; 
  var selcbu = oeve.getSource().getBindingContext("odata").getProperty("KTEXT");
  var otable = oeve.getSource().getTable("table");
  var ocolumn = otable.getColumns();

  }
 });
});
```

**header.view.xml**

```js
<mvc:View controllerName="NPAWRMA.controller.header" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  displayBlock="true" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout">
  <App id="idAppControl">
    <pages>
      <Page title="NPAW RMA Report">
        <content>
          <l:VerticalLayout>
            <Table id="table" growing="true" items="{odata>/npirevSet}">
              <columns>
                <Column>
                  <Text text="CBU" id="CbuShortNameColumnTitle"/>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                  <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label01}"/>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                  <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label02}"/>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                  <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label03}"/>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                  <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label04}"/>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                  <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label05}"/>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                  <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label06}"/>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                  <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label07}"/>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                  <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label08}"/>
                </Column>
              </columns>
              <items>
                <ColumnListItem type="Active" press="onPress">
                  <cells>
                    <Text text="{odata>KTEXT}"/>
                    <ObjectNumber number="{ path: 'odata>NpiPerc01', formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit' }"  state="{State01}"/>
                    <ObjectNumber number="{ path: 'odata>NpiPerc02', formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit' }"  state="{State02}"/>
                    <ObjectNumber number="{ path: 'odata>NpiPerc03', formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit' }"  state="{State03}"/>
                    <ObjectNumber number="{ path: 'odata>NpiPerc04', formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit' }"  state="{State04}"/>
                    <ObjectNumber number="{ path: 'odata>NpiPerc05', formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit' }"  state="{State05}"/>
                    <ObjectNumber number="{ path: 'odata>NpiPerc06', formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit' }"  state="{State06}"/>
                    <ObjectNumber number="{ path: 'odata>NpiPerc07', formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit' }"  state="{State07}"/>
                    <ObjectNumber number="{ path: 'odata>NpiPerc08', formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit' }"  state="{State08}"/>
                    <ObjectNumber number="{ path: 'odata>NpiPerc09', formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit' }"  state="{State09}"/>
                  </cells>
                </ColumnListItem>
              </items>
            </Table>
            <Table id="table1" class=".table1" growing="true" items="{odata>/npirevSet}">
              <columns>
                <Column>
                  <Text text="CBU" id="CbuShortNameColumnTitle1"/>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                  <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label01}"/>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                  <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label02}"/>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                  <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label03}"/>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                  <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label04}"/>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                  <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label05}"/>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                  <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label06}"/>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                  <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label07}"/>
                </Column>
                <Column>
                  <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label08}"/>
                </Column>
              </columns>
              <items>
                <ColumnListItem type="Active">
                  <cells>
                    <Text text="{odata>KTEXT}"/>
                    <ObjectNumber number="{ path: 'odata>NpiPerc01', formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit' }" unit="%" state="{State01}"/>
                    <ObjectNumber number="{ path: 'odata>NpiPerc02', formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit' }" unit="%" state="{State02}"/>
                    <ObjectNumber number="{ path: 'odata>NpiPerc03', formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit' }" unit="%" state="{State03}"/>
                    <ObjectNumber number="{ path: 'odata>NpiPerc04', formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit' }" unit="%" state="{State04}"/>
                    <ObjectNumber number="{ path: 'odata>NpiPerc05', formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit' }" unit="%" state="{State05}"/>
                    <ObjectNumber number="{ path: 'odata>NpiPerc06', formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit' }" unit="%" state="{State06}"/>
                    <ObjectNumber number="{ path: 'odata>NpiPerc07', formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit' }" unit="%" state="{State07}"/>
                    <ObjectNumber number="{ path: 'odata>NpiPerc08', formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit' }" unit="%" state="{State08}"/>
                    <ObjectNumber number="{ path: 'odata>NpiPerc09', formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit' }" unit="%" state="{State09}"/>
                  </cells>
                </ColumnListItem>
              </items>
            </Table>
          </l:VerticalLayout>
        </content>
      </Page>
    </pages>
  </App>
</mvc:View>
```

Comment: I dont understand what do you mean about "column index of selected row", can you explain more?

Comment: I need to capture table header text when user selected any value as shown in attached table output screenshot.Please provide any sample code for this issue.

Comment: I dont know if there is a better way, but in this case I would put CustomData at each control of line with the info you need.

Comment: @ibn...i didn't get you. Can you please provide any code snippet to understand it properly and implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you mean by "I want to read column index" but if you mean to know in which column you clicked when selecting the table row, then I think **it's not possible** from the API point of view.

`sap.m.Table` is a `ListBase` control. `sap.m.ColumnListItem` is a `ListItemBase` control. Therefore they handle events list-wise. This is only row relevant.

They only way I see is to handle events in each inner control, and get custom data from them. Otherwise the source of your click event will be the row or the table, but no info about the inner element you clicked

Comment: @Rafael...Can you please provide any sample code to understand and implement the same. If sap.m cannot be used then which class can be used to get the selected cell index.

Comment: I can't build a snippet, I'm answering with my phone. But check this link to decide which table to use  (select a column-based one): https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/148892ff9aea4a18b912829791e38f3e

Comment: @Rafael..i can see other tables but they don't support responsive features.Only sap.m is responsive.

Comment: Well... then there is no way to do it using the UI5 API with the controls you have. As I said, use clickable controls in each cell and make your logic whenever each one is clicked

Answer (score 0):

How @rafael-lópez-martínez said You cant get inner control on table event. But if You use a Button, Link or some control that has a press event you can do that.

I made a rapid sample on plunker sorry but I dont have much time . I copied some plunker and change that. So can have some stranger things.

Controller:

```
onPress: function(oeve) {
  oeve.getSource().getCustomData()[0].getKey();
  oeve.getSource().getCustomData()[0].getValue();

    }
```

View:

```
...
<ColumnListItem type="Active" >
    <cells>
    <Button text="{Name}" type="Transparent" app:colHeader="Col Text"         press="onPress"/>
    <Text text="{SupplierName}" maxLines="0"></Text>
    <Text text="{Width} x {Depth} x {Height} {DimUnit}" maxLines="0"></Text>
...
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/wtnnuk